# Relicensing CC BY 4.0 font after modification under OFL

Tags: cc-by, font, ofl

Is it possible to modify a font that was released under CC BY 4.0 and relicense it under SIL OFL License (or a dual-license of CC BY 4.0 and SIL OFL like [Linux Libertine fonts](https://linuxlibertine.sourceforge.net/Libertine-EN.html) did with GPL and SIL OFL)?

If there are contributions from downstream (using OFL), may I ask them to agree to use CC BY 4.0 to merge back into upstream such to maintain both version compatibility?

Comment: If you want to merge changes also upstream, why not use the same license? What reason do you have for relicensing to SIL OFL?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau actually, i am asking for my downstream authors that want to merge into my repo. I have no control over if they choose to use CC BY 4.0 or OFL. The main reason to use OFL is the font is originally part of a dataset, which has a lengthy attribution sentence. Using OFL for the font can avoid writing the attribution in the produced documents or posters.